# Access 2007 VBA GoToRecord issue

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an event table which records multiple events for each person. I've added an event_number field to allow a user to identify the order of events for each person and to move between them. Added a New Event button with the following code, which finds the last event number for the person and inserts a new line into the table with some basic data, such as their ID and and the next available event number. This works OK, but what I need to do is then move the event sub-form on so that this new event number is displaying on the form so that the rest of the data can be added. Tried various options around the DoCmd.GoToRecord, but can only manage to display a blank sub-form, and not one showing the newly entered event number. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub btnNewEvent_Click()  
   'add a new event by setting discriminator and event number
   Dim lngLast As Long
   Dim strQuery As String
   lngLast = DMax("[event_number]", "event", "[PersonID] = [Forms]![frmContainer]![txPersonID]")
   lngLast = lngLast + 1
   strQuery = "INSERT INTO event ( ID, event_discriminator, event_number ) " & _
           "VALUES ([Forms]![frmContainer]![txtPersonID], 'NR', " & lngLast & ")"
   DoCmd.RunSQL (strQuery)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on whether the subform is continuous or single form and how your application works. It may be sufficient to requery the subform and then find the relevant record:

```
''Running from the main form
Me.MySubformcontrolName.Form.Requery

Me.MySubformcontrolName.SetFocus
With Me.MySubformcontrolName.Form.Recordset
    .FindFirst "ID=" & lngLast 
End With
```

Or

```
''From the subform:
Me.Requery

With Me.Recordset
   .FindFirst "ID=" & lngLast 
   ''Other stuff
End With
```

It may suit to simply reset the subform record source to an SQL string that only includes the most recent record.

Note that the way you have chosen for getting a new number is unsafe in anything but a single user environment.

Comment: Is there a better way to set the next event number? The table currently has an Autonumber as the event_ID primary key. Need to be able to record approx 50 events for each person, 2400 people in all. Only one user will be responsible for the record of a specific person.

Comment: Single form based on the event table as recordset, but containing several subforms, each for a single table with event_ID as a foreign key and linking through a master/child link.

Comment: Event number is the next sequential number per person, is that right? Is a sequential number necessary?

Comment: BTW I have a system that adds events and I use a small unbound form to add each event, this ensures that all details are entered before the event is added to the table. To my mind, it is less confusing for the user to have a popup form.

Comment: Yes, event number is the next sequential number for per person. User needs to be able to work through a screen for each event for a person, up to maybe 50 events, and add all the data associated with the event, which goes into four tables. If I don't use a sequential number won't it be difficult for them to see easily where they are in the sequence, and also to be able to move directly to one particular event?

Comment: A particular event is indicated by the event autonumber combined with the person id. A date/timestamp is also a very useful indicator. Setting up a sequential number in a multiuser system is harder than it looks at first.

Comment: Thanks, Remou, I'll have another look at the design then